# magento widget does not appear

Tags: magento, widget

i've an module

Shop_All.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Shop_Productlists>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Shop_Productlists>
    </modules>
</config>
```

widget.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<widgets>
    <productlists_suggestion type="productlists/suggestion">
        <name>Suggestions</name>
        <description type="desc">Shows a product Grid</description>
    </productlists_suggestion>
</widgets>
```

Suggestion.php

```
<?php
class Shop_Productlists_Block_Suggestion extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract implements Mage_Widget_Block_Interface
{
    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $this->_prepareData();
        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }

    protected function _prepareData()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection();
        $collection->setPageSize(3);
        $this->getChild("suggestion_notoolbarlist")->setCollection($collection);
    }

    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $html = '...';
        return $html;
    }   
}
```

but the widget doesn't show up in admin panel under CMS->Widget-Instances->New Widget Instance

any ideas why? I've already deleted the cache dir and relogged to the admin panel

Other Blocks etc. of the "productlists" module are working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok found the problem,

in my widget.xml there was a space before

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

so it wasn't parsed. i think the parser should have shown an error. but he didn't